# Git Files are suddenly stripped from the Master Branch

Tags: git, github

Suddenly a large number of files that had versions on the Master branch have got delinked from the Master branch.
When we access the file directly via the Tag URL it shows the file , but displays this error

> This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.

Have 3 issues now.

1. A git Log is not showing any activity that might have caused this for a specific checkin tag
2. How do we get a complete listing of such files ?
3. What is shortest route the push these files back into the Master branch via a checkin ?

Additional Info
Say a file with a commit tag `[a5ae00d]` earlier (5 days ago) belong to the Master Branch, but now suddenly for the same commit tag `[a5ae00d]` , it shows as no longer part of the Master branch.

You can still access the file via the git URL

```
https://github.com//xxx/blob/a5ae00d/sub-path/filename
```

Comment: I'm confused about a few things. Git tags do not tag files? Does your local repo still have the master pointing to a valid commit? What list of files are you wanting? It seems like you may be confusing SVN with Git since you're using SVN style nomenclature. Please be careful with that as they work quite differently.

Comment: You can remove commits from a branch by force-pushing if the branch is not protected.... which might explain why the commit is not in that repo but is present in a fork.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Correction to what I said , when I used the word 'tag' I did not mean a Git tag, but used it in an english sense. I was referring to the SHA-1 hash or commit hash. 

We have to use git , and our requirement is to deal with per file basis , so we utilize the SHA-1 commit tag

Answer (score 1):

That is the case when the branch is reset to a different/older commit locally (or rebase, changing its history), and forced push (`git push --force`).

Check first if you see the change in your local `git reflog`.
Something like:

[image: https://rewind.com/wp-content/uploads/bh-images/VobjQ80.jpeg]

If you do not have work in progress, you could reset your branch to a commit of your choice with:

```
git switch -C myBranch aCommit
```

And then probably force push.

Note: GitHub does rarely, if ever, a [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) on your remote repository, so that past commit remain accessible.